# Why doesn't this function with boolean variable work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, boolean

I wrote simple code to show/hide some layers after clicking buttons (5 in total) and to change color of the clicked buttons. That works fine. But then I wanted to show a certain element - an arrow - only after clicking first button using a boolean variable and it's not working, the if statement never returns first (hooray) part. What am I missing?

```js
var click01 = false;

function allowright1() {
  if (click01 == true) {
    console.log('hoooray');
    $('#right_arrow').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
  } else {
    console.log('not working');
  }
};

$('#tile1_p1').click(function() {
  if ($('#1layers1').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#1layers2, #1layers3, #1layers4, #1layers5').removeClass('block').addClass('none');
      $('#tile2_p1, #tile3_p1, #tile4_p1, #tile5_p1').removeClass('orange');
      $('#1layers1').removeClass('none').addClass('block'); $('#tile1_p1').removeClass('white').addClass('orange');
      var click01 = true; 
      console.log('click01 ' + click01); 
      allowright1();
    }
    else if ($('#1layers1').css('display') == 'block') {
      $('#1layers1').removeClass('block').addClass('none');
      $('#tile1_p1').removeClass('orange').addClass('white');
    }
  });
```

Comment: You need to remove `var` with `click01 = true;` in the event handlers

Comment: With `var click01`, you are declaring the variable, you are assigning value to the global variable, just removed `var` keyword and you are done!

Comment: have a look at variables scopes and closures https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Comment: @glutengo Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: YES! removing "var" in the event handlers was the solution, many thanks guys :)

Answer (score 4):

You are not resassigning the top level variable `click01`.

By specifying `var click01 = true;` you are declaring a variable inside of your click handler that is different to the top level variable. If you remove the `var` it should work for you, e.g.

```
$(...).click(function() {
  ...
  click01 = true; // by removing var we reassign the top level variable
  ...
});
```